# Google Plus API, read a single public post in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rest, google-plus

I am trying to, as an exercise, read a public post I randomly found on the Internet.  The URL is: https://plus.google.com/107555023234041177814/posts/a5oZwq6h325

In all cases, trying to retrieve the Activity (a5oZwq6h325) of the post returns a 500 with a null message.

This is a simple #activities.get(activity_id) call on the GooglePlus API. I am authenticated, and the token is refreshed.

There is no option in the API documentation to supply a user_id, if that would help, that I can see.

Anyone know how to do this? Ideally in Ruby, but really any Google API client.

I'm using the standard https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client google client.

This is my code:

```
    def client
      @client ||= begin
        c = ::Google::Apis::PlusV1::PlusService.new
        c.authorization = oauth_authorization.to_authorization
        c.authorization.refresh!
        c
      end
    end

    client.get_activity('a5oZwq6h325')
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of the Ruby? The link you provide is the client lib I assume, which implies you've written at least some code that creates the client object and then does something with it. How does it compare with the example here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/get

Comment: The problem isn't getting things. If I search for an activity through the API, I can get it's ID and retrieve it fine. But, if I find a post through any other source, I can't seem to make it work... and there is no error message from google, just a 500.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a 500 from Google, though. This feels like it is resolving the REST request against some other server. You might want to check that you are actually reaching the host you think you are. Can you find a way of showing the raw HTTP request and result?